# ¿como puedo Llenar un array con datos de una consulta Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Es que estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto y quisiera saber si una manera de llenar un arreglo que me muestre algo parecido a esto:

[
{
"id": "1",
"modulo": "Oficina",
"acceso": "1"
}
]

Y de hacerlo, como puedo preguntar por ejemplo:¿que id tiene el modulo Oficina y su tipo de acceso? sin preguntar el índex del array

Comment: Si utilizas PDO de Php, puedes mirar la documentación https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
$arreglo = array();

    $datos = [
       'id' => 1,
       'modulo' => 'Oficina',
       'acceso' => '1'
    ];

$arreglo [] = $datos;
```

Para buscar de esta manera:

```
$campo = 'modulo';
$valor = 'Oficina';

function mifuncion($arreglo,$campo,$valor) {  

foreach($arreglo as $key => $arr) {

          if ( $arr[$campo] === $valor )
             echo ("El ID es: ".$key. " El acceso es: ". $arr['acceso']);    
          
return false; 
}
```

O puedes hacer esto:

```
$key = array_search('Oficina' , array_column($arreglo, 'modulo'));

echo ("El ID es: ".$key. " El acceso es: ". $arreglo[$key]['acceso'];
```